# Add Text and Image to Button in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to add both `Text` and `Image` on `Button` like:

```
Button(action: {}) {
        Image("gift")
        Text("Send")
            .padding(.horizontal)
    }
    .padding()
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .background(Color.gray)
    .cornerRadius(.infinity)
```

Button looks:

[image]

But I want to create this:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just put the `Image` and `Text` inside an `HStack`…

```
Button(action: {}) {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "gift")
        Text("Send")
    }
}
.padding()
.foregroundColor(.white)
.background(Color.gray)
.cornerRadius(.infinity)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 14, there's a standard view to accomplish this layout:

```
Button(action: {}) {
  Label("Send", image: "gift")
    .padding()
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .background(Color.gray)
    .cornerRadius(.infinity)
}
```

Also, adding the style modifiers to the content inside the `Button` view allows the button background to also be tappable. Adding the style modifiers outside the button will result in only the immediate area occupied by the image and text (the body of the `Button` view) being tappable, but not the surrounding button background (the gray area).

Answer (score 0):

Other solution, using direct constructor and buttonStyle with control size

```swift
Button("Send", systemImage: "gift", action: {
    print("send")
})
.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
.controlSize(.small)
```

If you prefere change background color using `.accentColor(.gray)` and foreground color with `foregroundStyle`

```swift
Button("Send", systemImage: "gift", action: {
    print("send")
})
.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
.controlSize(.small)
.accentColor(.gray)
.foregroundStyle(.white)
```

Answer (score -1):

> SwiftUI

It's working fine for button `Text`, `Image`, and `Shadow`

```
Button(action: {

            }) {
                HStack {
                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "Login")!)
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    Text("Login")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }


                .font(.system(size: 15))

                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("DarkGreen"), Color("LightGreen")]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
                .cornerRadius(40)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 60, alignment: .center)
                .shadow(color: .red, radius: 5, x: 0, y: 0)

            }
```

[image]